# The Snail in the Well - Solo learn project

Tags: javascript

In a way of trying to solve the 23 code project of SOLOLEARN JavaScript course known widely with (The Snail in the Well) .. I produced this code which is worked with case of input = 128
and failed with input = 42. What  I should modify in the code to implement the code successfully for all cases.

```
function main() {
    var depth = parseInt(readLine(), 10);
    //your code goes here
    
    let count=0
    for( let i=0;i<depth;){
        i+=5
        count++
    }
    console.log(count)
}
```

[The Original Challenge:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAhth.png)

P.S.
//You can replace this `[parseInt(readLine(), 10);]` with 42 and 128
and remove the main function to enable work at any code editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code will help you out with the problem.

```
function main() {
    var depth = parseInt(readLine(), 10);
    //your code goes here
    var days = 0;
    for(var distance = 0; distance <= depth;){
        days = days + 1;
        distance = distance + 7;
        if(distance >= depth){
            break;
        }
        else{
            distance = distance - 2;
        }

    }
    console.log(days);
    
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).